# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$hasDepartment

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $customers = $this->customerType->whereNull('deleted_at')->paginate(10);
    // please write the view code
    return view('admin.customer_type.index')->with(['customers' => $customers]);
}
```

show me that error in blade file.someone solve that please, thanks

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="visible">Department</label><br>
    <input name="hasDepartment" type="radio" value="ture" {!! $customers->hasDepartment == 'ture' ? 'checked' : '' !!}> True<br>
    <input name="hasDepartment" type="radio" value="false" {!! $customers->hasDepartment == 'false' ? 'checked' : '' !!}> False
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Loop through your data and then `hasDepartment()` menthod on customer object

Answer (score 0):

`$customers` is actually a paginator instance, you need to foreach on it to use every `$customer` like so :

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
    <fieldset>
        <label for="visible">Department</label><br>
        <input name="hasDepartment" type="radio" value="ture" {!! $customer->hasDepartment == 'ture' ? 'checked' : '' !!}> True<br>
        <input name="hasDepartment" type="radio" value="false" {!! $customer->hasDepartment == 'false' ? 'checked' : '' !!}> False
    </fieldset>
@endforeach
```